# Transforming Fractional Black Scholes PDE to heat equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Under specific substitutions, I am able to transform the Fractional Black-Scholes equation into the following:

$\displaystyle \frac{\partial V}{\partial t} = \displaystyle \frac{\partial^{\alpha} V}{\partial x^{\alpha}} + (\gamma-1)\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} - \gamma V $

This is surprisingly similar to an intermediate step of solving the traditional Black-Scholes equation using the heat equation (specifically when $\alpha =2$).  For my interest, I am looking to further transform this fractional partial differential equation into the fractional heat equation.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks!